# Get the next ten songs in iTunes DJ using AppleScript

Tags: applescript, itunes

I am creating an application using AppleScript and I want to display a list of the next ten (including the current) songs iTunes will play from iTunes DJ. I can't find it anywhere on the internet, Google, whatever so I asked it here. Can anyone help me? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following AppleScript will return the names of the songs in the iTunes DJ playlist:

```
tell application "iTunes"
    get name of every track of playlist "iTunes DJ"
end tell
```

The song names are returned in play order and will also include recently played songs (this can be configured in the iTunes DJ settings).